# Android App Not Working After Pressing Back Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I created an Android app which draws a small image to the screen and exits if you tap in the bottom 50px of the screen. When I tap there, it exits fine, however, when I press the back (or home) button to exit the application, it exits, but then says, "Unfortunately, Game Development has stopped." I also checked LogCat, and it showed that a Java NullPointerException occurred each time it stopped working. The output from LogCat was:

```
10-30 01:13:28.280: E/AndroidRuntime(15294): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1718
10-30 01:13:28.280: E/AndroidRuntime(15294): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 01:13:28.280: E/AndroidRuntime(15294):    at tricrose.gamedev.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:56)
10-30 01:13:28.280: E/AndroidRuntime(15294):    at tricrose.gamedev.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:30)
```

I have three Java classes: Game.java (the Activity), GameView.java (the SurfaceView), and GameThread.java (the main Thread).

The code is as follows:

Game.java:

```
package tricrose.gamedev;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Game extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = Game.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(new GameView(this));
        Log.d(TAG, "View added");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_game, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

GameView.java:

```
package tricrose.gamedev;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public static final String TAG = GameView.class.getSimpleName();
    private GameThread thread;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (e.getY() > getHeight() - 60) {
                thread.setRunning(false);
                ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1), 10, 10, null);
    }
}
```

GameThread.java:

```
package tricrose.gamedev;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class GameThread extends Thread {

    public static final String TAG = GameThread.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean running;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GameView gameView;

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameView gameView) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gameView = gameView;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        while (running) {
            canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    this.gameView.onDraw(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've searched all over the internet for a solution, and I cannot find one which has actually worked, so any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to find the solution! It turned out that I should have checked if the canvas was null before calling onDraw, and if it was null, then quit the application by finishing the activity. I found the solution on JavaCodeGeeks.com, where I was looking at an Android tutorial. Thanks everyone for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

why you have doing drawing from two places from onDraw and GameThread run method. I think you need to remove onDraw do every drawing from GameThread rlun method only.

Comment: I'm only doing the drawing in the GameView class, but the onDraw function will never get called if I remove it from the GameThread class. I tried it, and because it was the loop in GameThread that was calling the onDraw function, the image did not appear.

Comment: do not try to call onDraw from the GameThread put that drawing code in run and remove onDraw there is no need of that.

Comment: It's a very good idea, although it did not work, because it's the same code getting called each time the thread loops, whether it is in the onDraw function or not. So, unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but your app might still be drawing while the app is trying to exit. In you onDraw method you call this line of code (which is probably your cause of problem):
`canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1), 10, 10, null);`

In that case you might not have resuorces available anymore ;)

You can try to:
1. Put a class private bitmap variable into your GameView Class: 
`private Bitmap mBitmap;`
2. Load the bitmap in your GameView constructor: 
`mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1);`
3. Draw using the (already loaded) bitmap: 
`canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 10, 10, null);`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work. I think you're right in that the thread does not end when the application does, so it throws a NullPointerException, although creating a private bitmap in the GameView class still gave the same error.

Really good suggestion, though!

Comment: it's an ugly thing to do, but in case you just want to get past this problem you could put this in your onDraw method: `code`try{/*you drawing code here*/}catch(NullPointerException e){Log.e("MyTAG", "Ignoring NPE", e);}